# multiple values for a filter query as a string type in apache solr

Tags: apache, solr

Friends

I indexed mysql data to apache solr as propertyname, id , and location as set, when i quered it shows like

```
{
        "locality": "MG Road - Residency Rd",
        "id": "212473",
        "propertyName": [
          "Vivanta by Taj - M G Road"
        ]
      },
      {
        "locality": "Indiranagar - Old Airport Rd",
        "id": "198732",
        "propertyName": [
          "The Leela Palace Bangalore"
        ]
      },
      {
        "locality": "Sankey Road - Palace Road - Race Course",
        "id": "198402",
        "propertyName": [
          "Taj West End"
        ]
      },
      {
        "locality": "Indiranagar - Old Airport Rd",
        "id": "366878",
        "propertyName": [
          "Matthan Hotel"
        ]
      },
```

Here locality is a text-type (String) , if I search fq=locality:"Indiranagar - Old Airport Rd", it shows Indiranagar - Old Airport Rd  properties, but I want to search multiple locality like 
fq=locality:"Indiranagar - Old Airport Rd" AND "Jaya Nagar - JP Nagar", how to do it in apache solr as well as ModifiableSolrParams

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command: Please try it.

q=locality:"Indiranagar - Old Airport Rd"+AND+locality:"Jaya Nagar - JP Nagar"

note: it performs a exact search.

Answer (score 0):

Friends

Finally I got an answer
q=locality:(Indiranagar - Old Airport Rd  Jaya Nagar - JP Nagar)
it shows all the results by words like Indiranagar, Old, rd, Jaya, Nagar etc...
finally I did this way q=locality:(Indiranagar Jaya)
now its going to search for two words only.